# Apply a user-made function to vector with other arguments

Tags: r

I created two functions in R

```
orderstat <- function(pop,ord=1){
  sort(pop)[ord]
}
```

and

```
sc= function(y.pop,y.fun,atr){
  N=length(y.pop)+1
  sapply(y.fun,function(y.new){
    N*(atr(c(y.new,y.pop))-atr(y.pop))
  })
}
```

Both functions work individually. When I try,

```
run=seq(0,10,1)
sc(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), run, orderstat, ord=2)
```

I get the error

> Error in sc(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), run, orderstat, ord = 2) :
> unused argument (ord = 2)

I was hoping that this would apply the function orderstat when ord=2 in the function sc I created. Any ideas why this does not work.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but aren't you basically calling a function to operate within a function? So, for any function you have to provide the parameters. So, for orderstat you need (pop, ord). Which means in the sc function you still need to give the orderstat its parameters right?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I needed to let my sc function have the ability to take more arguments. Like so

```
sc= function(y.pop,y.val,atr,...){
  N=length(y.pop)+1
  sapply(y.val,function(y.new){
    N*(atr(c(y.new,y.pop),...)-atr(y.pop,...))
  })
}
```